# Ant migration tool - keep track as Change Set

Tags: ant, change-set, xml, package.xml

Is there a way to deploy meta data through ant migration tool and keep track of this deployment in salesforce?
In the same way as change set appear as inbound change set.

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

No, not really. When you perform a deployment through the API (including use of the Ant Migration Tool), it doesn't become available in the user interface for review, approval, and execution. A record is kept under Deployment Status in Setup, but it's not the same interface as Change Sets and doesn't provide much detail.

If you need that kind of control over your deployment process, you'll likely need to add both process and tooling to your SDLC. There are a variety of commercial offerings that provide deployment-management features, or you can assemble your own out of the basic components - source control (Git), a deployment tool (preferably `sfdx`; Ant is obsolete), and an automated pipeline (GitHub Actions, CircleCI, Jenkins...)

Your process can then include whatever review and audit logging that you need, typically backed by your source control system as the source of truth.